# I have been installing using an exe setup and want to change to Wix

Tags: windows-installer

I have been installing using an exe setup and want to change to Wix.  This means there are many instances of the application already installed by users, but none of them using Windows Installer.

Are there any issues to look out for when changing to Windows Installer?  For instance, what does WI do when installing/upgrading over an app that was installed prior to WI?  Do I have to worry about that?

Comment: If by "exe setup" you mean some sort of non-Windows Installer based script style setup, there is a lot to learn. It'll be really hard to answer than in the SO format.

Comment: You're right, there is a lot to learn.  But I can't find anything on this question in the documentation.  Maybe that means it shouldn't be a big issue.  I guess I'll just have to try it and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to detect if the users have a previous installation and then trigger the uninstall process, or block the application from installing. When I have previously had to do this, I simply use a Launch Condition to detect the previous installation, and display a message asking the user to uninstall the old version via control panel before proceeding - it wasn't the best user experience, but it was the most reliable solution.

Comment: Thank you, sascha, I had imagined something like this but it's good to get the word from somone who's been down that road.